# Error IONIC EMULATE

Tags: ios, ionic

Tengo un error en la configuración de ionic.

Quiero emular iOS con ionic emulate iOS y me aparece este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al hacer un ionic info aparece lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya instale Xcode y también iOS-sim pero sigue saliendo eso.

---

Re instale el Xcode y ahora me apareció en ionic info que sí está instalado Xcode al igual que iOS-sim pero iOS-deploy no. Al instalar me sale este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aparentemente se aprecia como si estuviera instalado el deploy.

Comment: y el ios-deploy?

Comment: Reinstale xcode desde el app store y ahora me aparece, tmbn se instalo el iOS-sim pero el iOS-deploy no me deja me manda un error

Comment: Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Ionic Framework Version: 1.3.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v6.5.0
Xcode version: Xcode 7.3.1 Build version 7D1014

Comment: No sabía que una tarea de deploy no estuviese asociada al mundo del desarrollo. Favor de re pensar los votos a cierre para esta pregunta.